# How to format autocomplete dropdown to get two equally spaced columns?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

In the jquery [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) 
How can I get constant equal spacing between label and value, that are displayed in autocomplete dropdown.

The code below will have distorted items and not clear two columns

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label+ "&nbsp;" + item.value + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );    


        };
```

I want something like below in autocomplete dropdown:

```
label              value
l                  This is value
This is label      v
Wow this is label  THANKS!
```

So that one can clearly differentiate among the two[label and value].

Comment: You mean just the format?

Answer (score -1):

Well, no need to modify much. More CSS work here:

```
$( "<li>" )
            .append( "<a class='half'>" +  'LABEL' + "</a><a class='half black'>" + 'value' + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( $('ul') );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kkfkx6v1/

Just add in CSS.

```
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 50%;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it is not working with autocomplete jquery. Though it indeed shows two column, both label and value are put in first column itself. Also when the size of columns does not grow according to size of the label. But I guess I did not mention it clearly in op so including it now.

I tried to make some changes but still its not working

Comment: One possibility is to use a monospaced font and add spaces to ensure each column has the space # of spaces. Not pretty, but best I can find for autocomplete so far.